# How to reuse page css design to another

Tags: css, search, drupal

I'm new to Drupal8, and I have a default search page with CSS design. also, I have another page for search-api-solr page. I want to have the same CSS design on the default search page into the search-api-solr page.

Note: both pages have the same content, a search field with button and tags section and grid for the result.

How can I get that done?
Any advice?